# Missing Parameters using POST in R for API

Tags: r, api, post, httr

I am currently using POST function (package httr) to submit some texts to an API to get processed output, my code is wrote as follows.

```
url = "..."
client_id = "..."
client_secret = "..."
request_body = jsonlite::toJSON(list(src = c("吃饭")), pretty=TRUE, auto_unbox=TRUE)
secret = jsonlite::base64_enc(paste(client_id, client_secret, sep = ":"))
req = httr::POST(url, 
             httr::add_headers(
               "Authorization" = paste("Basic", gsub("\n", "", secret)),
               "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8"),
             body = request_body,verbose()
);
content(req)
```

Then I get the following error message:

```
"missing parameters: {client_id, client_secret}"
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code or step? Many thanks!

Comment: Does `POST(url, authenticate(client_id, client_secret))` do the trick?

Comment: @thothal thanks, I tried this, but once I run content(req), it always return "missing parameters: {client_id, client_secret}"

Comment: looks like it's expecting those two parameters in the request body. what type of API (with what authentication) are you using? Do you maybe need to obtain a token first?

Comment: @RolandASc  http: POST url parameters: client_id, client_secret, Header：Content-Type：application/json;charset=UTF-8